# Git rebase a rather large patch queue?

Tags: git, diff, patch, rebase

I have a fairly complicated rebase of meta-layer patch queues to perform, and while I've been using Git for about 2 years, I wouldn't consider myself proficient...

I have a base application, which I'll refer to as App, and it requires 2 meta-layers to be applied in order, all with their own Git development branches.

Meta-layer ML_A is applied 1st, and Meta-layer ML_B is applied 2nd, and ML_B cannot be applied before ML_A due to dependencies in ML_A being applied 1st.

Meta-layer ML_A has a single extensive patch, A01.patch, and Meta-layer ML_B has a long patch queue of patches B01.patch through B90.patch.

I removed B44.patch and B51.patch from Meta-layer ML_B, extracted the code, and re-inserted it as part of the extensive A01.patch for Meta-layer ML_A. It was time consuming, but simple enough, and the ML_A meta-layer applies to App cleanly and functions as it should.

But! Now I must rebase thousands and thousands of lines of diff patch code in Meta-layer ML_B to reflect the updated Meta-layer ML_A changes to App because ML_B and ML_A touch a lot of the same files. I know I can spend the next several weeks applying ML_B patches individually and correcting patch line numbers when a patch doesn't apply, but I've heard there are some snazzy Git commands that will really expedite this process.

Anybody know what the best Git practices here would be? Git format-patch? Git rebase-patch?

Comment: So, you had this: `A,B01,B02...B90`, and you would like to have this: `A'(which is A+B44+B50),B01',B02'...B43',B45'...B50',B52'..B90'`. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

I didn't find any super magical Git solutions in my searches, but I figured out a decent workflow. I could write a script to help with what I'm doing, but I'm in a bit of crunch time and will probably write the script after my deadline for use in the future.

Comment: Pseudo workflow, starting from App_Dev branch:
**1)** git apply A01.patch -v
**2)** git checkout -b App_after_A01, git add -A, git commit -m "<message>"
**3)** git apply <next_sequential_patch>.patch -v
**4)** Was it a perfectly clean apply?
**Yes:** git checkout -b App_after_<applied_patch>, git add -A, git commit -m "<message>", go back to step 3
**No:** git reset --hard, fix fuzz and line numbers, git diff <head of last patch cleanly applied> ~/ B<patch_number>.patch, go back to step 3

Comment: If you have a patch series which applies without conflicts to some commit it it always better to make it once and then rebase/cherry-pick to another place. 1) you don't have to care about commit messages. 2) conflict resolution is more convenient in case of cherry-pick

Answer (score 0):

Your reordered patches should produce same result by the new `B50'` as older series by `B51`. So, if you do not have a requirement to preserve all of them individually you can save on conflict resolution by just picking the B51's worktree:

- apply the original series; remember commits related to patches `B51` and `B90`
- `git reset --hard $original_commit`
- apply and commit the modified A patch
- `git reset --hard B51`
- `git reset --soft HEAD@{1}`
- `git commit -m 'patches B00-B50, excluding B44'` - commits exactly same tree as originally was at `B51`
- `git cherry-pick B51..B90` - they should apply cleanly